# JS not detecting text field

Tags: javascript

I have a validation where I have two variables v1 and v2. If v2 > v1, it should do the following:

```
var val1 = "<[OriginalAmount]>";
var val2 = "<[UpdatedAmount]>";
if (val2 > val1) {
document.getElementById("btnInstantAddButtons").disabled = true;
return[["<span style='color: red'>The new charge amount cannot exceed the original charge amount!</span>"]];
}
else{
document.getElementById("btnInstantAddButtons").disabled = false;
}
```

On the front end, when the user enters a value for v2, sometimes it validates and throws the error message, and sometimes it doesn't. This script is from a SAAS BPM tool, no html required.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: `v1` and `v2` variables do not appear at Question. Can you include `html`, full `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Hey, why are you returning a 2D array in the first if statement block?

Comment: Add the html code

Comment: Why do you use `return`?

Comment: The return should be throwing the message on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your values to Float value.

```
val1 = parseFloat(val1);
val2 = parseFloat(val2);
```

I think you are trying to compare two strings.

If the value you want to parse is not a number will return NaN